# FileReader error when reading an excel file in node.js

Tags: node.js, xlsx, filereader

I'm trying to read an excel file I have sent to the server using the module 'FileReader' and 'xlsx'.

```
var file = body.file;

var xlsx = require('xlsx');
var FileReader = require('FileReader');

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
   var data = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
   var workbook = xlsx.read(data, { type: 'array' });
};
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

But I get this error when I run it:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'bufferjs/concat'
Require stack:
- C:\GitHub\ECM-Back\node_modules\FileReader\FileReader.js
- C:\GitHub\ECM-Back\controllers\projects.controller.js
- C:\GitHub\ECM-Back\routes\projects.route.js
- C:\GitHub\ECM-Back\app.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at new FileReader (C:\GitHub\ECM-Back\node_modules\FileReader\FileReader.js:62:5)
    at projects_importData (C:\GitHub\ECM-Back\controllers\projects.controller.js:184:16)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\GitHub\ECM-Back\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\GitHub\ECM-Back\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at C:\GitHub\ECM-Back\controllers\auth.controller.js:650:37
    at tryCatcher (C:\GitHub\ECM-Back\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\GitHub\ECM-Back\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:517:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\GitHub\ECM-Back\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:574:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\GitHub\ECM-Back\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:619:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\GitHub\ECM-Back\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:699:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (C:\GitHub\ECM-Back\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (C:\GitHub\ECM-Back\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)
```

I've already installed 'bufferjs' into my node.js system.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was getting this error due to the fact that I was using the new keyworkd for FileReader.